# Make HTTP Get request in iOS with params

Tags: ios, http

I want to make an HTTP GET request from my iOS client and place in the request params. I have written code that performs a POST request, where it was very easy to use setHTTPBody to place a NSData* object in the request. How is this done for a GET request?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a GET method the parameters are passed in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - so you suffix your URL with something like ?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3. You may need to [percent-encode](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios) your query string if it contains characters like space, & or =